# C# Windows IoT core - Auto Scroll text in Textblock from left to right continuously

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-10-iot-core

I am working on a Digital Signage project using Windows IoT core. So far I managed to design the grid and scroll images and videos. Now I have added a text block at the bottom of the grid and text in it should continuously scroll from left to right

For more detail example I need a MARQUEE of text in the bottom side.

Main page XAML code:

```
<Page
x:Class="Digital_Notiec_Board_V1._2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Digital_Notiec_Board_V1._2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="#FF222222" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="1800"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="imageInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="audioInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="videoInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF5A80FF">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ScrollText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Text="AJ Y" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"  SelectionHighlightColor="#FF2D5DFF">
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear as to what you're trying to do here. Do you have a sample code or demo project or something that gives us the idea on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. To be clear Iam making an Universal Windows App and above is my XAML code which displays images. I want to add a Textblock in the bottom of the screen and want to give MARQUEE effect to the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you need to show a `Marquee` text only then I would advise you to use a custom control that allows you to put a text as a `marquee`.

Luckily, there is a `GitHub` repo for the same. You can check it out on `GitHub at [MarqueeTextControl](https://github.com/sanje2v/MarqueeTextControl)

works perfectly fine, I just tried it. If you need any further help, please use the comments section.